# jQuery Mobile Date & Time Input Not Working

Tags: jquery, date, mobile, time

jquery mobile provides its own way for inputting date and time, which is

```
<input type = "date" />
<input type = "time" />
```

This is working fine on a browser and on some phones (android). It brings up the native menu with the slide bar to select times and date. However, on an android tablet, it does not work and the input simply serves as any regular text input.

I tried using the datepicker plugin before but it was very slow...

Is there any way i can fix this issue? Or are there any useful, simple plugins I can use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  //reset type=date inputs to text
  $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.degradeInputs.date = true;
  });   
</script>
```

Comment: in your comment you said this resets the date inputs to text? i dont want it to...